# Using multiple JPanels in a single JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I've basically been trying to make a menu for a game by using a JFrame and switching out 2 JPanels (one for the menu and one for the actual game). I'm trying to implement the most basic format I can think of but can't seem to get it to work. If anybody could explain what's wrong with the code I would appreciate it.

Here's my JFrame, menu panel, and ActionListener

```
package buttonMenu;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Skeleton extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel menu;
JButton button;

public Skeleton(){

setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(400, 400);
setVisible(true);

menu = new JPanel();
button = new JButton("button");

menu.setSize(400, 400);
menu.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
menu.setVisible(true);
menu.add(button);

button.setLocation(200, 200);
button.addActionListener(this);

add(menu, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
    JPanel panel = Game.Game();
    this.remove(menu);
    this.add(panel);   
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Skeleton();
}
}
```

The actionPerformed calls the panel created in this class

```
package buttonMenu;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Game{

public static JPanel Game(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(400, 400);
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    return panel;       
}

}
```

Again, if anybody could explain to me what's wrong with this code I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding/removing components, you will need to `revalidate` the parent container to force it to relay itself out...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
    JPanel panel = Game.Game();
    this.remove(menu);
    this.add(panel);   
    this.revalidate();
}
```

A better solution would be to use something like a `CardLayout`

Take a look at [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

ps- I should add.  You should avoid extending directly from `JFrame`, instead create your application entire on a base component, like a `JPanel`.  When you need to display it, create an instance of JFrame and add the application component to it.  This way your application becomes more flexible in terms of deployment and re-use

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've never used revalidate but it's working now. Also, thanks for the link, it looks like the card layout is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use validate() method to see the changes.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
    JPanel panel = Game.Game();
    this.remove(menu);
    this.add(panel);   
    this.validate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*What's wrong with my code* may be kind of a vague question, but I'll sort some points:

- `extends JFrame`: You're not really *extending* `JFrame`, you're just using one, as part of your GUI.
- As other answers mention, you should `revalidate()` after adding/removing components.
- `menu.setVisible(true)`, usually this isn't needed.
- Maybe not *wrong*, but I usually build all my interface first (*ie*, creating and adding the initial components), and only then set the dimensions and visibility of the frame.
- You're running all that code in the `main` thread; Swing components aren't thread-safe. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information on that.
- I know this is for a game, but is absolute positioning in your panels really needed? Use Layout managers if possible (with an exception for your game panel, which will probably do only custom painting).

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I just realized I forgot to specify what my code was doing. Thanks for the advice though, it's working now.